# JPA - mapping additional calculated value from an entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called `Taxi` which has got its location information saved in it. I have a stored procedure which returns this entity fields and an additional field called 'distance' which is calculated by the stored procedure. The question is I am returning Taxi entity from the stored procedure which obviously doesn't have the distance field, how do I get this calculated distance field?

This is how it looks:

```
List<Taxi> getTaxisAroundMe(Integer customerId,Integer distance);
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce:

```
 @Entity
 @Immutable
 public class TaxiReadOnly extends Taxi {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long /*?*/ id;

    private Integer distance;
    //get+set
 }
```

Then:

```
public interface TaxiReadOnlyRepository {
   List<TaxiReadOnly> calcDistance(/*input params*/);
}


// as before
public interface TaxiRepository extends CrudRepository<Taxi, Long>,
  //but now with
  TaxiReadOnlyRepository {}


// and
public class TaxiReadOnlyRepositoryImpl implements TaxiReadOnlyRepository {
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
   @Override
   public List<TaxiReadOnly> calcDistance(/*input params*/) {
       return em.createNativeQuery("BEGIN call_ur_procedure(:inParam1, ...); END;")
      //.setParameter("inParam1", inParam1)
      .getResultList();
  }
}
```

see:

- https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-view-hibernate/
- https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thanks alot for this, the TaxiReadOnly works fine, but now when I findAll from Taxi it says Unknown column 'taxi0_.distance'

Comment: for now I have duplicated Taxi named it TaxiReadOnly and added Entity and @Immutable annotations only, and created repo class for it which seems to be working fine but I am not is not the 'proper' of doing it, any help will be much appreciated